# BuddyPress registration form shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm trying to get the registration form for BuddyPress.
I searching for a shortcode or just php code.

I've try to copy the field in template's of buddypress plugin. But it's dosen't work.

Here is the code I place in a custom post type.

```
<div id="buddypress">

    <?php do_action( 'bp_before_register_page' ); ?>

    <div class="page" id="register-page">

        <form action="" name="signup_form" id="signup_form" class="standard-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <?php if ( 'registration-disabled' == bp_get_current_signup_step() ) : ?>
            <?php do_action( 'template_notices' ); ?>
            <?php do_action( 'bp_before_registration_disabled' ); ?>

                <p><?php _e( 'User registration is currently not allowed.', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>

            <?php do_action( 'bp_after_registration_disabled' ); ?>
        <?php endif; // registration-disabled signup setp ?>

        <?php if ( 'request-details' == bp_get_current_signup_step() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'template_notices' ); ?>

            <p><?php _e( 'Registering for this site is easy. Just fill in the fields below, and we\'ll get a new account set up for you in no time.', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>

            <?php do_action( 'bp_before_account_details_fields' ); ?>

            <div class="register-section" id="basic-details-section">

                <?php /***** Basic Account Details ******/ ?>

                <h4><?php _e( 'Account Details', 'buddypress' ); ?></h4>

                <label for="signup_username"><?php _e( 'Username', 'buddypress' ); ?> <?php _e( '(required)', 'buddypress' ); ?></label>
                <?php do_action( 'bp_signup_username_errors' ); ?>
                <input type="text" name="signup_username" id="signup_username" value="<?php bp_signup_username_value(); ?>" />

                <label for="signup_email"><?php _e( 'Email Address', 'buddypress' ); ?> <?php _e( '(required)', 'buddypress' ); ?></label>
                <?php do_action( 'bp_signup_email_errors' ); ?>
                <input type="text" name="signup_email" id="signup_email" value="<?php bp_signup_email_value(); ?>" />

                <label for="signup_password"><?php _e( 'Choose a Password', 'buddypress' ); ?> <?php _e( '(required)', 'buddypress' ); ?></label>
                <?php do_action( 'bp_signup_password_errors' ); ?>
                <input type="password" name="signup_password" id="signup_password" value="" class="password-entry" />
                <div id="pass-strength-result"></div>

                <label for="signup_password_confirm"><?php _e( 'Confirm Password', 'buddypress' ); ?> <?php _e( '(required)', 'buddypress' ); ?></label>
                <?php do_action( 'bp_signup_password_confirm_errors' ); ?>
                <input type="password" name="signup_password_confirm" id="signup_password_confirm" value="" class="password-entry-confirm" />

                <?php do_action( 'bp_account_details_fields' ); ?>

            </div><!-- #basic-details-section -->

            <?php do_action( 'bp_after_account_details_fields' ); ?>

            <?php /***** Extra Profile Details ******/ ?>

            <?php if ( bp_is_active( 'xprofile' ) ) : ?>

                <?php do_action( 'bp_before_signup_profile_fields' ); ?>

                <div class="register-section" id="profile-details-section">

                    <h4><?php _e( 'Profile Details', 'buddypress' ); ?></h4>

                    <?php /* Use the profile field loop to render input fields for the 'base' profile field group */ ?>
                    <?php if ( bp_is_active( 'xprofile' ) ) : if ( bp_has_profile( array( 'profile_group_id' => 1, 'fetch_field_data' => false ) ) ) : while ( bp_profile_groups() ) : bp_the_profile_group(); ?>

                    <?php while ( bp_profile_fields() ) : bp_the_profile_field(); ?>

                        <div<?php bp_field_css_class( 'editfield' ); ?>>

                            <?php
                            $field_type = bp_xprofile_create_field_type( bp_get_the_profile_field_type() );
                            $field_type->edit_field_html();

                            do_action( 'bp_custom_profile_edit_fields_pre_visibility' );

                            if ( bp_current_user_can( 'bp_xprofile_change_field_visibility' ) ) : ?>
                                <p class="field-visibility-settings-toggle" id="field-visibility-settings-toggle-<?php bp_the_profile_field_id() ?>">
                                    <?php printf( __( 'This field can be seen by: <span class="current-visibility-level">%s</span>', 'buddypress' ), bp_get_the_profile_field_visibility_level_label() ) ?> <a href="#" class="visibility-toggle-link"><?php _ex( 'Change', 'Change profile field visibility level', 'buddypress' ); ?></a>
                                </p>

                                <div class="field-visibility-settings" id="field-visibility-settings-<?php bp_the_profile_field_id() ?>">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <legend><?php _e( 'Who can see this field?', 'buddypress' ) ?></legend>

                                        <?php bp_profile_visibility_radio_buttons() ?>

                                    </fieldset>
                                    <a class="field-visibility-settings-close" href="#"><?php _e( 'Close', 'buddypress' ) ?></a>

                                </div>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <p class="field-visibility-settings-notoggle" id="field-visibility-settings-toggle-<?php bp_the_profile_field_id() ?>">
                                    <?php printf( __( 'This field can be seen by: <span class="current-visibility-level">%s</span>', 'buddypress' ), bp_get_the_profile_field_visibility_level_label() ) ?>
                                </p>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <?php do_action( 'bp_custom_profile_edit_fields' ); ?>

                            <p class="description"><?php bp_the_profile_field_description(); ?></p>

                        </div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <input type="hidden" name="signup_profile_field_ids" id="signup_profile_field_ids" value="<?php bp_the_profile_field_ids(); ?>" />

                    <?php endwhile; endif; endif; ?>

                    <?php do_action( 'bp_signup_profile_fields' ); ?>

                </div><!-- #profile-details-section -->

                <?php do_action( 'bp_after_signup_profile_fields' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( bp_get_blog_signup_allowed() ) : ?>

                <?php do_action( 'bp_before_blog_details_fields' ); ?>

                <?php /***** Blog Creation Details ******/ ?>

                <div class="register-section" id="blog-details-section">

                    <h4><?php _e( 'Blog Details', 'buddypress' ); ?></h4>

                    <p><input type="checkbox" name="signup_with_blog" id="signup_with_blog" value="1"<?php if ( (int) bp_get_signup_with_blog_value() ) : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> /> <?php _e( 'Yes, I\'d like to create a new site', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>

                    <div id="blog-details"<?php if ( (int) bp_get_signup_with_blog_value() ) : ?>class="show"<?php endif; ?>>

                        <label for="signup_blog_url"><?php _e( 'Blog URL', 'buddypress' ); ?> <?php _e( '(required)', 'buddypress' ); ?></label>
                        <?php do_action( 'bp_signup_blog_url_errors' ); ?>

                        <?php if ( is_subdomain_install() ) : ?>
                            http:// <input type="text" name="signup_blog_url" id="signup_blog_url" value="<?php bp_signup_blog_url_value(); ?>" /> .<?php bp_signup_subdomain_base(); ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?> <input type="text" name="signup_blog_url" id="signup_blog_url" value="<?php bp_signup_blog_url_value(); ?>" />
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <label for="signup_blog_title"><?php _e( 'Site Title', 'buddypress' ); ?> <?php _e( '(required)', 'buddypress' ); ?></label>
                        <?php do_action( 'bp_signup_blog_title_errors' ); ?>
                        <input type="text" name="signup_blog_title" id="signup_blog_title" value="<?php bp_signup_blog_title_value(); ?>" />

                        <span class="label"><?php _e( 'I would like my site to appear in search engines, and in public listings around this network.', 'buddypress' ); ?></span>
                        <?php do_action( 'bp_signup_blog_privacy_errors' ); ?>

                        <label><input type="radio" name="signup_blog_privacy" id="signup_blog_privacy_public" value="public"<?php if ( 'public' == bp_get_signup_blog_privacy_value() || !bp_get_signup_blog_privacy_value() ) : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> /> <?php _e( 'Yes', 'buddypress' ); ?></label>
                        <label><input type="radio" name="signup_blog_privacy" id="signup_blog_privacy_private" value="private"<?php if ( 'private' == bp_get_signup_blog_privacy_value() ) : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> /> <?php _e( 'No', 'buddypress' ); ?></label>

                        <?php do_action( 'bp_blog_details_fields' ); ?>

                    </div>

                </div><!-- #blog-details-section -->

                <?php do_action( 'bp_after_blog_details_fields' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php do_action( 'bp_before_registration_submit_buttons' ); ?>

            <div class="submit">
                <input type="submit" name="signup_submit" id="signup_submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Complete Sign Up', 'buddypress' ); ?>" />
            </div>

            <?php do_action( 'bp_after_registration_submit_buttons' ); ?>

            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'bp_new_signup' ); ?>

        <?php endif; // request-details signup step ?>

        <?php if ( 'completed-confirmation' == bp_get_current_signup_step() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'template_notices' ); ?>
            <?php do_action( 'bp_before_registration_confirmed' ); ?>

            <?php if ( bp_registration_needs_activation() ) : ?>
                <p><?php _e( 'You have successfully created your account! To begin using this site you will need to activate your account via the email we have just sent to your address.', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php _e( 'You have successfully created your account! Please log in using the username and password you have just created.', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php do_action( 'bp_after_registration_confirmed' ); ?>

        <?php endif; // completed-confirmation signup step ?>

        <?php do_action( 'bp_custom_signup_steps' ); ?>

        </form>

    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'bp_after_register_page' ); ?>

</div><!-- #buddypress -->
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what you're doing here?

Comment: @MHakvoort, a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not happy with the default form that shows up? When buddypress is installed it creates a few pages on your site. If you navigate to Settings->BuddyPress ->pages, you will see that the register page is pointing to... well Register :) There should be a "Register" page present in your All Pages. This is installed by buddypress

Answer (score 0):

By Default, buddypress installs a Register page at : www.yoursite.com/Register

Open it while you are not log in and you can see the Registration Form.

Answer (score 0):

Go to buddypress plugin template folder:

wp-content\plugins\buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress

Copy the buddypress folder and paste it into your theme's root.

Now go to:

wp-content\YOURTHEME\buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\members folder and you will find a register.php file. You can work with it.